# NBViewer Won't Load Jupyter Notebook Dynamic Content

Tags: python, html, json, jupyter-notebook

I want to have slideshows with buttons to flip through images on my Jupyter Notebook analysis, but NBViewer only renders the buttons, and won't load the images. It works fine on my Jupyter Notebook on my PC.

Is there a different service or something that I can add to the code to make dynamic content like a slideshow with buttons show up?

Thank you.

Comment: nbviewer has a way to present as slides if you notebook has slideshow metadata, see [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jupyter/IO9LGZchURw). I'm not sure RISE puts the metadata though. Full RISE with an active Python kernel backed by MyBInder is easier and more feature-rich. if you were still having installation problems, you can go to [github.com/binder-examples/jupyter-rise](https://github.com/binder-examples/jupyter-rise) and click the launch binder button to run Jupyter-rise in your browser using a remote machine. You can use that repo as a template to make your own repo and...

Comment: <continued>then add your content to it and adjust the launch button URL to use your repo, if you are okay with your content being public in Github. Note that it will still work if you aren't comfortable with leaving your content on Github because you can launch a session and then upload your notebook to the running session.

Comment: Note in the nbviewer rendered example linked to from [there](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jupyter/IO9LGZchURw) (mentioned in the first part of my comment), which is at https://nbviewer.org/format/slides/github/tonyfast/powersoften/blob/master/pydata/index.ipynb#/ , you have to look carefully in the bottom right corner to see **the light gray forward buttons that you can click on**. The contrast is lacking and easy to overlook unless you know what you are looking for.